# Emulator of Nokia S40 6th edition SDK is not running....What should I do to run this As soon as possible?

Tags: java-me, emulation, nokia-s40

I have install Nokia S40 6th edition SDK(emulator of 6260 slide phone) & using Netbeans 7.2 IDE for my app development. In NetBeans when I run my project with S40 SDK configuration it gives me following error:-

Creating New "Series 40 6th Edition SDK" Instance ...

"Series 40 6th Edition SDK" Connection Terminated

E:\My Netbeans project\MidletGPS\nbproject\build-impl.xml:782: Execution failed with error code -1072365566.

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

**build-impl.xml:782:-**

`<nb-run jadfile="${dist.dir}/${dist.jad}" jarfile="${dist.dir}/${dist.jar}" jadurl="${dist.jad.url}" device="${platform.device}" platformhome="${platform.home}" platformtype="${platform.type}" execmethod="${run.method}" securitydomain="${evaluated.run.security.domain}" commandline="${platform.runcommandline}" classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${dist.dir}/${dist.jar}" cmdoptions="${run.cmd.options}"/>`

When I went to run directly emulator, SDK runs cmd & by showing message -

Creating New "Series 40 6th Edition SDK" Instance ...

"Series 40 6th Edition SDK" Connection Terminated"
it got closed without running actual emulator.

I am not getting what should I do to overcome from this?? Please help......

**Note: I already have Nokia 1.0 & 2.0 SDK**

Answer (score 1):

My emulator use to do that too. What I do to get it back is the following. I stop all the javaw process and the Nokia sdk too, and I try to restart the emulator. If this doesn't work, stop javaw process and Nokia sdk and launch the emulator from the Nokia/Devices/bin/emulator.exe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning and then building before running it?
I guess its not able to find the jar file

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved friends.... thanx for the suggestions but real problem is Nokia 1.0 SDK. Running of Nokia's 1.0 & S40 SDK simultaneously on computer will either run Nokia 1.0 or run Nokia S40 SDK... You can install & run any one them not both of them....